# Which author has had the most books adapted for film?

Tags: book-adaptation

Which author has had the most books adapted for film ?

By this I mean actual *novels* that were released before the film (and not novelisations of films or screenplays or graphic novels/comics). Short stories are counted a 'books' too.

Also, please count the *books* not the *films* so multiple adaptions of 'Dracula' for example only count as one book.

Comment: are you counting number of movies or number of books adapted? Multiple  adaptations of the same work will skew the count radically versus an author who has had many distinct works adapted. Bram Stoker would score well on movies but all from a single book, Dracula; Agatha Christie would score many adaptations of many books.

Comment: @matt_black - question edited

Comment: Ian Fleming is going to take some beating. Then again, John le Carré & Agatha Christie could be formidable opponents...

Comment: @Tetsujin Or Shakesepeare.

Comment: @Chenmunka - Close enough to be recognisable - so 'No' to World war Z and 'Yes' to I am legend

Comment: Do they have to be complete novels; would short stories also count? That would bring Philip K Dick into the running, although his count is probably still eclipsed by others'. [edit noted!]

Comment: @AdrianWragg- Short stories are OK

Comment: Gotta be Stephen King, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not counting sequels or remakes, [Stephen King](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_adaptations_of_works_by_Stephen_King#Film) has ~40 based directly from a novel, novella or short story authored by him, with 4 more adaptations in the pipeline for 2017.

To Get to near 40, I did count Creepshow sequels that used previously unadapted King short stories. I invite spot checks of my hasty tally :)

Comment: Nice answer - going to be hard to beat :)

Comment: My first thought was King or Crichton, but King probably wins.

Comment: I'm still confused what we're counting. The phrasing "~40 based directly from a novel" sounds like you're counting 40 films, not 40 books. Imdb ascribes 372 writing credits to Charles Dickens and 1248 writing credits to William Shakespeare.

Comment: @Chaim, but most of Dickens and Shakespeare are remakes of the same handful of stories. Plus, Shakespeare was not an author even if he has had more than 40 plays adapted into films.

Comment: @Chaim Shakespeare has exactly 36 original works (Get out of here Bacon & Marlowe...) that have been adapted and re-adapted. I was counting unique adaptations, that being, the first adaptation of a unique work. No Carrie remakes and no Children of the Corn IIs, neither of which have basis in a  unique, previously unadapted work.

Comment: @Darren But Darren's first point was also my point. It seemed that the case for Stephen King was stated in terms of the number of movies. Are we to compare the number of movies (based on books) or the number of books (adapted into movies)? And what makes you believe your second point, that King but not Shakespeare was an author?

Comment: @Chaim, Shakespeare was a playwright, not an author.

Comment: @Chaim Ah I see what your question was now. I phrased it backwards from the OP in my answer but the relation is the same: One unique film to one unique work.

Comment: Wikipedia asserts that Arthur Conan-Doyle wrote 4 novels and 56 short stories about Sherlock Holmes (not counting his many other books). Which of them were adapted? Would television adaptations count?

Comment: I didn't notice until now the down-voted answer which also mentions Arthur Conan Doyle.

Comment: Agatha Christie seems like a good bet for someone who might beat King. IMDB lists 148 films or TV series crediting her sources (14 books of short stories and 66 novels). And it counts *series* not *stories* so the count of unique stories might be quite high.

Comment: @matt_black she would wipe the floor if the question included TV shows-the series Poirot adapted every single Poirot novel & short story.

Comment: The number of movies or TV shows is irrelevant to the question. The issue is the number of original works. Christie would be my bet but sources need to be quoted.

Answer (score -5):

Facetious answer: God probably wins if you count the number of films that are based on the Bible.

Two more that might be in with a shout:

Arthur Conan Doyle - I'm sure every Sherlock Holmes novel and short story has probably been adapted in some fashion.

Edgar Rice Burroghs - Depends on how many Tarzan films are direct adaptations of stories he wrote. Plus John Carter (of Mars).

Comment: God's my favorite author

Comment: Oh dear, down voters don't have a sense of humour?

Comment: Down voted because it really isn't a very good answer.  All I see is "probably" and "depends on".